# How to email video from iOS to Android?

Tags: ios, video, android, mov

Videos shot with iOS are saved as MOV container. MOV is not supported by Android. So what is the best way to email a video to Android? I'm really surprised I couldn't find an easy answer for this with googling. It would be great if it automatically transwrapped to MP4.

I don't want to use a computer, and I would prefer not to use a third-party app if possible.

Comment: a MOV file is essentially an mp4. Can you rename the .mov to .mp4?

Comment: On a computer, this would be trivial. Maybe I can do it in the Dropbox app. Do you know if this will make it playable on Android?

Comment: Not having an Android phone I could not tell you that. I suggested that as a "why don't you try this because it *sounds* like it might work." It's a comment and not an answer as I am not certain of it.